# Way to display those nodes in a view that are related to any other node of a different type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have two content types - "Blog" and "News". I am using a reference field to relate blog nodes to news nodes. Now, for the news landing page, I need a block view that displays "Related blogs" i.e. it lists blogs that are related to any news node.

The news landing page is a panel page with a main view that lists all news nodes. The "Related blogs" block will be placed below the main block.

Is there a way to achieve this "Related blogs" block using views?

I am using Drupal7 and I am free to use any module for the relations, apart from references.

Comment: How would you like it to evaluate "Related"?

Comment: jsheffers, as I said, at present I have a reference field for relating content, but I am open for other options that may make it easier to build the related content block.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new view, add the reference field as a relationship, and the NID as the contextual filter.  Also set the contextual filter to Provide a default value and choose Content ID from URL.  The add the block to your news pages.

Comment: That is the common approach for displaying related content on node pages. However, I am trying to display the related content in a panel page and I need to show blog nodes that are related to any news node.

Comment: Then just remove the contextual filter.  If you're using panels just add the custom block you created with the view above to your panel page.