# Using EntityReference, how do I create a Drupal block that shows which nodes reference the current node?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, entityreference

So let's say I have a node for a hotel and a node for a restaurant.  I want a list of restaurant nodes that I have explicitly attached to the hotel node using EntityReference.  Meaning, there is a field in the restaurant content type that refers to a hotel node.

It seems like I should be able to create a block view that will see what node the user is looking at, and show a list of related nodes, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I have got a block that shows all restaurants, and have been trying to get contextual filters to work, but any time I try to create a contextual filter, I get this error: "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."  This seems like it should be simple, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need contextual filters for this.  I answered a question similar to this here: [Way to display those nodes in a view that are related to any other node of a different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025713/way-to-display-those-nodes-in-a-view-that-are-related-to-any-other-node-of-a-dif/10033972#10033972)

Comment: That's pretty close to what I did when I got the "illegal choice" error.  I'll give your exact answer a try and see if it works for me.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, so I followed your instructions on the other question.  1. Create a new view of restaurants in block form.  2. Add a new relationship with the following: "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity - A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via field_hotel"  3. Add a contextual filter with the following: "Content: Nid - The node ID.", selecting the relationship I just made.  4. Selected "Provide Default Value" of "Content ID from URL".   When I click "Apply", I get this error: "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."  Do you think there is a bug?

Comment: P.S. I tried it with the latest recommended release and the dev release.

Comment: OK, it does appear as if there is a bug of some sort in this form somewhere.  When I found the error message in /includes/form.inc and commented out the form_error call, just to see, it worked perfectly.  Thanks for your help.